# TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.unstable_createElement) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, font-awesome

I'm trying to use FontAwesome icons for my React Native project, and installed the packages as specified [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome). But when I finished downloading the `react-native-svg` package, I got the following error in my web browser — `TypeError: (0 , _reactNative.unstable_createElement) is not a function` pointing to this code:

```
export class Svg extends WebShape {
  346 |   render(): JSX.Element {
> 347 |     return createElement('svg', prepare(this));
  348 |   }
  349 | }
```

What's interesting is that there is no error on the iOS simulator, but only the web browser... I've tried searching for this issue, but I couldn't find anything to help my case. What's going wrong here and how can I fix this?